# 50% packet loss on ubuntu 16.04 (and 17.04)

Tags: networking, internet, ping

Recently I've started getting terrible packet loss (up to 50-60%) on ubuntu. (even when pinging local addresses, like my router).
The packet loss begins at intervals and lasts for about 20 seconds, then stops. There are also no messages in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` about that.

I've thought it's a router issue, but pinging google on my laptop with wireless connection results in 0 packet loss.

So I've thought it's a cable issue, and I've connected the cable to my laptop (ubuntu 17) and it got a packet loss too. So I started to think it's the cable.

But then I've booted into windows from my pc (using the same cable) and realized that pinging from windows does not have any packet loss.

I've already tried rebooting and restarting networking service but it didn't help.

Example `ping -OD google.com` output when the packet loss occurs:

```
[1511445212.704065] 64 bytes from cache.google.com (80.253.19.184): icmp_seq=320 ttl=60 time=1.55 ms
[1511445213.705529] 64 bytes from cache.google.com (80.253.19.184): icmp_seq=321 ttl=60 time=1.40 ms
[1511445215.705067] no answer yet for icmp_seq=322
[1511445216.705062] no answer yet for icmp_seq=323
[1511445217.705074] no answer yet for icmp_seq=324
[1511445218.705068] no answer yet for icmp_seq=325
[1511445219.705084] no answer yet for icmp_seq=326
[1511445220.705077] no answer yet for icmp_seq=327
[1511445221.705068] no answer yet for icmp_seq=328
[1511445222.705069] no answer yet for icmp_seq=329
[1511445223.705079] no answer yet for icmp_seq=330
[1511445224.705070] no answer yet for icmp_seq=331
[1511445225.705089] no answer yet for icmp_seq=332
[1511445226.705063] no answer yet for icmp_seq=333
[1511445227.705074] no answer yet for icmp_seq=334
[1511445228.705093] no answer yet for icmp_seq=335
[1511445229.705087] no answer yet for icmp_seq=336
[1511445230.705075] no answer yet for icmp_seq=337
[1511445231.705078] no answer yet for icmp_seq=338
[1511445232.705069] no answer yet for icmp_seq=339
[1511445233.705066] no answer yet for icmp_seq=340
[1511445234.705066] no answer yet for icmp_seq=341
[1511445235.705068] no answer yet for icmp_seq=342
[1511445236.705075] no answer yet for icmp_seq=343
[1511445237.705069] no answer yet for icmp_seq=344
[1511445238.705067] no answer yet for icmp_seq=345
[1511445239.705068] no answer yet for icmp_seq=346
[1511445240.705088] no answer yet for icmp_seq=347
[1511445241.705077] no answer yet for icmp_seq=348
[1511445242.705088] no answer yet for icmp_seq=349
[1511445243.705088] no answer yet for icmp_seq=350
[1511445244.705087] no answer yet for icmp_seq=351
[1511445244.706562] 64 bytes from cache.google.com (80.253.19.184): icmp_seq=352 ttl=60 time=1.40 ms
[1511445245.708165] 64 bytes from cache.google.com (80.253.19.184): icmp_seq=353 ttl=60 time=1.49 ms
```

`ifconfig` output:

```
enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:37:8e:ac  
          inet addr:192.168.10.134  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::922b:34ff:fe37:8eac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:181121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:122080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:161672155 (161.6 MB)  TX bytes:9620508 (9.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:177093 (177.0 KB)  TX bytes:177093 (177.0 KB)
```

`ethtool -i enp5s0` output:

```
driver: atl1c
version: 1.0.1.1-NAPI
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:05:00.0
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Edit: commands like `sudo service networking restart`, `sudo ifdown -a && sudo ifup -a` restore connection, but it breaks again soon after.

Also, when the connection is broken, I can still receive data (watch youtube videos, receive messages in chats, see other players moving in game, hear other people talk in discord, but I can't send any data, can't load any pages (GET requests don't get sent), nobody hears me)

Edit 2: Same happens on Ubuntu 17.04 and live USB ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: This is probably not an issue with Ubuntu, but more likely a problem with the NIC itself, cables, or your router. You say there is no packet loss in Windows, but did not include any output from running a ping there. There could theoretically be some issue with the driver itself, but you have not specified what your hardware actually is.

Comment: Well, I didn't include ping output from windows, but trust me, there were no lost packets over about 20 minutes. My hardware is 05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved by buying a new cable - that one was bent really badly in one place. But I'm still not sure why Windows didn't have any packet loss.

Comment: This randomly started to happen to me, it was driving me crazy, but turns out it's just an Ethernet cable that some how got lose because i was connecting/disconnecting cables from the switch/router to test something else, thanks for the tip!